# Get container for a class in Slim Framework 3

Tags: containers, slim-3

I have DIC Configuration

```
$container = $app->getContainer();
$container['renderer'] = function ($c) {
    $settings = $c->get('settings')['renderer'];
    return new Slim\Views\PhpRenderer($settings['template_path']);
};
```

And send container in the construct method for class OrderModel

```
$this->get('setoutsite/{id}', function ($req, $res, $args) {
    $um = new OrderModel($container);
    return $res
    ->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')
    ->getBody()
    ->write(
        json_encode(
            $um->SetOrderOutSite($args['id'])
            )
        );
});
```

But the parameter is null, when the constructor get

```
class OrderModel
{

    private $db;

    private $table = 'orden';

    private $response;

    private $conf_emblue;

    private $emblue;

    private $phpView;

    public function __construct( Container $c = null)
    {
        $this->db = Database::StartUp();
        $this->response = new Response();
        $this->conf_emblue = new ConfigEmblue();
        $this->emblue = new RestEmblue();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is that you are not passing the container through the route function to resolve this just change your code like this :
pass the $container with **use**

```
$this->get('setoutsite/{id}', function ($req, $res, $args) use($container) {
$um = new OrderModel($container);
return $res
->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')
->getBody()
->write(
    json_encode(
        $um->SetOrderOutSite($args['id'])
        )
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code like following

In you dependency registration, register `OrderModel` instance.

```
$container[OrderModel::class] = function($containerInstance) {
    return new OrderModel($containerInstance);
};
```

and in route (assuming `$app` is Slim app instance),

```
$app->get('setoutsite/{id}', function ($req, $res, $args) use($container) {
   $um = $container->get(OrderModel::class);
   return $response->withJson($um->SetOrderOutSite($args['id']));
});
```